# Name of the event at the end of Avengers: Infinity War

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In *Avengers: Infinity War* when the Avengers lost and 50% started disintegrating, was there a name given to the event?  The Event, The Disintegration, The Loss?

Comment: Do you mean a "public" name? Because every character calls it the Snap, but then again every character we're shown with knows the whole thing with Thanos. The general population, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Jenayah That brings up an interesting question; what _does_ the general public think happened?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's called **the Decimation**.

> Marvel has been carefully avoiding exploring the consequences of the snap, so as not to spoil any plot details for *Avengers 4*. With the sole exception of one of the post-credits scenes of *Ant-Man & the Wasp*, none of the movies have been set in this period. The Marvel Television shows have dodged the snap - even *Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.*, whose fifth season was heavily influenced by Thanos' attack. This silence has come to an end, however with the publication of Brandon T. Snider's *The Cosmic Quest Volume Two: Aftermath*. A young adult book, it doesn't go into great detail about the horror of it all, settling for throwaway references to the chaos that ensued on a global scale. But, for the first time, it officially reveals the in-universe name for the event fans have long been calling the "Snappening."
>
> **To the Earth's surviving population, the moment when half the life on the planet crumbled to dust is known as "The Decimation."**
>
> <sub>[*Marvel Reveals Official Name For Thanos' Snap*, Thomas Bacon for Screenrant, December 5th, 2018](https://screenrant.com/avengers-infinity-war-thanos-snap-name-decimation/)</sub>

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe the "event" is specifically referred to by name but I'd suggest that it's probably called **"The Vanishing"**.

Circumstantial evidence provided by the memorial in San Francisco visited by Scott Lang.

The lost people are called "The Vanished".

[image]

Alternatively, it seems general knowledge that Thanos was responsible for what happened and so it could be referred to a **"Before Thanos"** and **"After Thanos"**